# Could not locate file. NodeJS,MySQL,Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I've encountered a problem.
I want to make on an RageMultiplayer Server a MySQL Connection.
I typed in this:

```
    const mysql = require("mysql");
    const db = mysql.createConnection({
        host:'127.0.0.1',// host of server
        user:'root',// MySQL user
        password:'mystrongpasswort',// MySQL password
        database:'test'// MySQL database
    });
```

Error: D:\Programme\RAGEMP\client_resources\185.245.96.9_22005\function\fahrzeug.js:17: ReferenceError: mysql is not defined

const db = mysql.createConnection({

Comment: Please share the exact error message.

Comment: Now Changed. There is the exact Error.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems correct, but the client-side is not NodeJS. Database connection should be done on the server-side.